# Case in Select Query has syntax error

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to return a boolean according to a condition on one of the column of my table. I tested it in SQL Server 2014 and it works, but I have no experience in Access.

This is the query I have at the moment, using Access 2007.

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN Type = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EstContrat
FROM Historique_EnTete
```

Type has the `Text` type.

I have translated the error message to :

```
"Syntax error (missing operator) in the expression << (CASE WHEN Type = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >>"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you are missing that there's no `CASE` expression is Access

Comment: @Lamak Well, that explains a lot lol, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In access you have **[IIF](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php)**

```
SELECT IIF(Type = 'C', 1, 0 ) AS EstContrat
FROM Historique_EnTete
```

As Lamak say you also have **[SWITCH](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/switch.php)**

Comment: or `switch` in case that there's more than just one condition